# GoogleApiClient class not found Error

Tags: android, google-api, google-plus

I am developing an android app with Google+ SignIn. I imported google-play-services_lib, but the code is showing GoogleApiClient class not found error. Also com.google.android.gms.common.api package is not found in the project.[image]

What i gotta do to resolve this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure that's the latest version of the client?  GoogleApiClient is in a package called com.google.android.gms.common.api and I don't see that in your screenshot.